# JPA insert foreign key as null

Tags: java, jpa

I have 2 entities that one of them is the foreign key of the other:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XXXX")
@XmlRootElement
public class Drfacopt implements Serializable {
    @Id    
    @NotNull
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "OPCOD")
    private Short optionCode;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "OPCODDH")
    private String optionCodeDescription;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "YYYY")
@XmlRootElement
public class Drfac03f implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected Drfac03fPK drfac03fPK;    

    @JoinColumn(name = "F3OPT", referencedColumnName = "OPCOD" )
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)    
    private Drfacopt relationCode;
}
```

when I'm trying to insert a new record using `em.persist(drfac03f)` I get this exception:

```
During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST
```

How can I insert the foreign key as null? I want to have the @Null for so when the user inserts a record directly to Drfacopt it wont be null or zero, but if it's through Drfac03f then it can be inserted as null. how can this be done?

Comment: Show the code where you insert and get the exception.

Comment: Did you create the `Entities` yourself or did you generate them from the database?

Comment: @Darwind: the entities are generated from the database..

Comment: @acdcjunior: the exception was after the code `em.persist(drfac03f);`

Comment: Dont leave that in a comment, add that to the question. Whats the content of `drfac03f`?

Comment: If you want relationCode to be null in database set it to null in drfac03f. And please, choose better names. This can't even be pronounced.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I tried taht, but I get this exception: `Null values not allowed in column or variable F3OPT`.. any other way to do this?

Comment: @acdcjunior: I've updated it in my question. I want to insert to `drfac03f` Drfacopt  object when it's `relationCode` is zero, which means I want to add it as null or any other way that will let me insert the record..

Comment: Try changing `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` to `@ManyToOne` and then try inserting it as `null` again.

Comment: @acdcjunior: I changed it like you said, and tried it with null and got this: `Null values not allowed in column or variable F3OPT` (and it's because it's a numeric field inside the database and can't be null), and also tried it with `new Drfacopt(0)` and got this: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.dortal.drfacutative.tables.Drfacopt.Drfacopt[ optionCode=0 ].`. what should I do??

Comment: Look, columns with numeric values like `INTEGER` **do can** receive `NULL`, all it has to do is be configured to so. I'm thinking the problem is that the column in the table is `NOT NULL`, is it?

Comment: @acdcjunior: In the database the column is set as `NUMERIC` - so it can't have null value. it has to be inserted as 0 (zero value). so if `Drfacopt` is null I want the value inside 'F3OPT' to be zero. how can I do that? thank's for your help!

Comment: That's what I'm saying, `NUMERIC` column can be `NULL`, look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0bea/1

Comment: Ok! Should I summarize the comments in an answer so you can accept it and close the question?

Comment: @acdcjunior: That will be greate! thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736061/a-new-object-was-found-through-a-relationship-that-was-not-marked-cascade-persis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try `em.persist(myObj)` and get the error:

> During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

It means the object (`myObj`) you are trying to persist **has a field/property** (say `foreignProperty`) that has a [foreign key] relationship with `myObj` and neither `foreignProperty` was persisted before `myObj`, nor the relationship was marked with `CascadeType.PERSIST`, that is, **`foreignProperty` does not exist in the database yet**.

The solution is to persist the `foreignProperty` **before** or, as said, set the relationship `CascadeType.PERSIST`.

> How can I insert the foreign key as null?

Since you want to set the foreign field as `null`, you shouldn't persist it before (there's no need to "persist" a `null` object).

So, just simply **set the field as `null`** and proceed to persist `myObj` as usual.

> I tried to persist, but got the error "`Null values not allowed in column or variable ...`"

This error message states that you are trying to persist a `null` value somewhere you couldn't. There are some possible reasons:

- Most probably **the actual column in the database is `NOT NULL`**. **Solution:** Set it to `NULL`.
- The relationship is marked as `(optional = false)`. The solution would be to set that `optional` attribute as `true` or remove it altogether. <sup>(Note: this is possibly implementation dependent so it requires confirmation.)</sup>