# JPA - During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I'm using JPA and am having trouble persisting an entity.

[Program ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIkoJ.png)

The program is a simple shopping cart web app:
A customer may place many orders that may contain many products.

Customer table -> orderly (order) table -> order_product table -> product table

My issue is I am attempting to persist an order entity and have been unsuccessful, getting the error in the title of this post.

You can see some output below showing the state of the object before attempting to persist.

`Info:   entity.Orderly[ id=null ]
Info:   Date Placed: Tue May 26 00:00:00 AEST 2020
Info:   Status: PROCESSING
Info:   Grand Total: 782.00
Info:   Customer ID: entity.Customer[ id=1 ]
Info:   Order Products List: [entity.OrderProduct[ orderProductPK=entity.OrderProductPK[ orderId=null, productId=2 ] ]]`

Here are the pertinent bits of my Orderly entity

```
public class Orderly implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
...
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Customer customerId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderly")
    private Collection<OrderProduct> orderProductCollection;
```

Here are the pertinent bits of my OrderProduct entity

```
public class OrderProduct implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected OrderProductPK orderProductPK;
...
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Customer customerId;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderly")
    private Collection<OrderProduct> orderProductCollection;
```

Add order method in my OrderFacade:

```
Orderly o = orderDTO2DAO(order);

// set up customer on order
o.setCustomerId(customerDTO2DAO(customerFacade.getRecordFromUsername(username)));

// set up products contained within order
o.setOrderProductCollection(getOrderProducts(order, products));

if (o == null)
{
    return false;
}

create(o);

return true;
```

Setting up the OrderProducts collection in my Order entity

```
ArrayList<OrderProduct> opList = new ArrayList<OrderProduct>();

        for(ProductDTO p : products)
        {
            OrderProductPK opPK = new OrderProductPK(p.getId());
            OrderProduct op = new OrderProduct(opPK, p.getQuantity(), getLineTotal(p));
            op.setOrderly(orderDTO2DAO(order));
            op.setProduct(productDTO2DAO(p));
            opList.add(op);
        }

return opList;
```

In the create method I simply call persist(order).

I have a suspicion that it is because the Order_Product table is weak and uses order_id and product_id as a composite key.

Here's the Glassfish server log with some of the stacktrace

`Warning:   java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: entity.Orderly[ id=null ].
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.discoverUnregisteredNewObjects(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.calculateChanges(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:723)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
    at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:723)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy291.addOrder(Unknown Source)
    at web.OrderManagedBean.confirmOrder(OrderManagedBean.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Comment: so u want to save orderly but it not saved? any error stacktrace?

Comment: Yep that's the gist of it. I added the stacktrace to the post.

Comment: have u try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736061/a-new-object-was-found-through-a-relationship-that-was-not-marked-cascade-persis) ?